# Shimano shoe size

Tags: shimano, shoes

I am riding clipless with the MT43 shoes I bought at my LBS.
They are great,... when it is not cold outside... and now it is cold outside... and my toes are freezing.
I was thinking of getting Shimano MW81 Gore-Tex Winter SPD Boots but my LBS does not sell it and is not willing to order (they're promoting their own brand and only sell two Shimano references).
So I was considering buying online.
I know Shimano is know to have "funny" sizing, and that one usually needs one size or two over one's usual size.
The thing is, my MT43s fit perfectly (tried 4 different sizes at the LBS) and I ended up with EU 46 size while I usually wear for city and sports shoes 46 to 48 depending on the brand which feels weird since Shimano shoes usually require one size over the usual...

And now for my upcoming MW81: can I rely on my MT43 experience and get the same size? or should I get one size higher? (or should I order both and return the one that does not fit... but that wold cost me some extra postage)?

Also, the 46-48 non-Shimano-shoe-size I had mentionned earlier was already true over a year ago and since then, I lost 80 pounds and when I look at my feet, they do look a little skinnier (I can now see some veins and bones which was not the case before), can this mean that I might have dropped to 45 for usual urban and 46 for Shimano? I mean my old urban shoes still fit and I have not felt much of a difference but I had to toss that idea in the pool...

Thank you all!

Comment: I lost a load of weight a couple of years ago - probably around the same as you if my inbuilt lb-kg converter is working properly - and I too have observed a drop in shoe size from 44 to 43. I was quite surprised too since I thought my foot size would stay pretty much constant. But in any case you could easily verify that by going into any shoe shop before you order your boots.

Comment: Good idea, I'll do that. And thanks for the testimony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll should be fine ordering the same size as what you currently have. Just order one pair and if they don't fit to your liking send them back. You'll probably get it right the first time, but if not some online shops offer free return shipping (Amazon?). You have a better than 50/50 chance of saving yourself the hassle of dealing with a return if you order just one pair.

Answer (score 0):

A few forum searches gave me the recommendation to purchase the same shimano MW-81 shoes one (european) size larger than my regular shoes. I think that was a good choice, especially since I tend to wear thicker socks with them in cold weather.